# connect.facebook.net has been blocked

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, sdk, scrollbars

I'm using JavaScript SDK to remove the scrollbars from my iframe application. My company blocks "connect.facebook.net" which hosts the JS SDK.

Is there any way to host this javascript on heroku - the cloud platform that Facebook partenerd with?

Or is there any way to resize the iframe without having to use the javascript sdk?

Answer (score 0):

No you won't be able to host this on a separate domain.  It needs to be hosted on a Facebook domain/subdomain due to cross-domain restrictions.  You should contact your administrators to unblock Facebook connect libraries.